# Jammed Thumb Mouse Buttons (Gaming Mouse)

Tags: mouse-buttons

My mouse's side buttons no longer work. I've tried using a screwdriver but cannot figure out why they will not click anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouse buttons are usually a small micro-switch. That is what provides the click.

If jammed, there is not much you can do about it.

If there are small screws holding the top and bottom half together, you can try removing the screws, separating the halves, and then see if you can free the button from inside.

If not, then you need to replace the mouse.

Comment: … or the buttons. They're dirt cheap but hellishly fiddly to swap out.